# OpenCV Python QueryFrame function leaks memory

Tags: python, video, opencv

I'm using the `Python` interface for `OpenCV 2.2.0`. The following code works correctly for grabbing frames from a video file:

```
for f in range(1, frameCount):
    # grab the left and right frames
    frameL = cv.QueryFrame(videoL)
    frameR = cv.QueryFrame(videoR)
    # create the image for the first frame
    if f==1:
        imageL = cv.CreateImage(cv.GetSize(frameL), frameL.depth, frameL.channels)
        imageR = cv.CreateImage(cv.GetSize(frameR), frameR.depth, frameR.channels)
    # update the images
    cv.Copy(frameL, imageL)
    cv.Copy(frameR, imageR)
```

However, as I process more video frames, the memory consumption keeps increasing. According to the OpenCV documentation, we don't need to release the memory for the image data obtained by `cv.QueryFrame`. Is this still correct? I tried "del frameL" and "del frameR", but it didn't solve the problem. Is there a bug in the Python wrapper for OpenCV in this particular function?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should allocate memory for both images once:
   imageL = cv.CreateImageHeader(cv.GetSize(frameL), frameL.depth, frameL.channels)
   imageR = cv.CreateImageHeader(cv.GetSize(frameR), frameR.depth, frameR.channels)

then begin your loop and set the data:

```
cv.SetData(frameL, imageL)
cv.SetData(frameR, imageR)
```

so something like

```
for f in range(1, frameCount):
    # grab the left and right frames
    frameL = cv.QueryFrame(videoL)
    frameR = cv.QueryFrame(videoR)
    # create the image for the first frame
    if f==1:
        imageL = cv.CreateImageHeader(cv.GetSize(frameL), frameL.depth, frameL.channels)
        imageR = cv.CreateImageHeader(cv.GetSize(frameR), frameR.depth, frameR.channels)
    # update the images
    cv.SetData(frameL, imageL)
    cv.SetData(frameR, imageR)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, if you look at the original code, I only create the image data (imageL/imageR) once. I tried your version, too. The memory leak problem is still there; that's why I suspect that the QueryFrame function leaks memory.