# Why using QueryFrame of OpenCV in a loop keeps increasing memory in python?

Tags: python, opencv

This script takes a photo from the webcam and saves every hour:

```
import cv
import time

def f():
    camera = cv.CreateCameraCapture(0)
    time_ = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S")
    frame = cv.QueryFrame(camera)
    cv.SaveImage("%s.png" % time_, frame)

while True:
    f()
    time.sleep(3600)
```

I am creating capture capture every time because I may want to access the webcam while the script is running. But that doesn't seem to be the problem. QueryFrame just keeps increasing memory. It is not garbage collected after the function exits. By searching I found [OpenCV Python QueryFrame function leaks memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5318311/opencv-python-queryframe-function-leaks-memory) and tried line this:

```
def f():
    global n
    camera = cv.CreateCameraCapture(0)
    time_ = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S")
    frame = cv.QueryFrame(camera)
    if n == 1:
        image = cv.CreateImageHeader(cv.GetSize(frame), frame.depth,
                frame.channels)
        n = 2
    cv.SetData(frame, image)
    cv.SaveImage("%s.png" % time_, image)
```

But it gives this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "log_webcam.py", line 20, in <module>
    f()
  File "log_webcam.py", line 17, in f
    cv.SaveImage("%s.png" % time_, image)
TypeError: IplImage argument 'image' has no data
```

**Edit:** I am using python-opencv 2.3.1-7 from ubuntu repo.